# plot data organized by rows

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The data are organized where the first column are year and next are monthly average, I need plot x-->month and y--> monthly average and the data base is organized first column= year next columns are monthly mean (12 values) corresponding to year, like that:

```
1871  -0.107   0.004  -0.503  -0.650  -0.379   0.025   0.317   0.027  -0.732  -0.685   0.037   0.566
1872   0.376  -0.241  -0.904  -1.019   0.367   0.282  -0.061   0.597   0.779   0.818   1.070   1.203
1873   0.831   0.762   0.379  -0.028   0.014   0.349   0.189   0.428  -0.170   0.643   0.859   0.317
1874   0.063   0.125  -0.068  -0.124   0.365   0.535   0.693   1.298   0.554   0.566   0.889   0.185
1875  -0.369  -0.764  -1.238   0.111   0.683   0.696   0.505   1.008   1.210   0.945  -0.307  -0.184
```

Similar to this graph:

[image: here is an example]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried yet, in how far did it not work, what prevents you from reaching the goal, how should the final plot look like, how should different columns be interpreted (do you want 12 different values per year or one average value per year)? Please [edit] your question to include the answers to all of those questions, together with a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Still some questions missing. What have you tried yet? in how far did it not work? what prevents you from reaching the goal? Also, which tools are you using? Are you happy with pandas or numpy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears you think this is a code-writing service.

Comment: OK!!! No problem